# "Inline" labels in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs

Is it possible to render a chart with "inline" labels between horizontal bars in ChartJS?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`chartjs-plugin-datalabels`](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels) for this which is very useful when displaying labels on data for any type of charts and is highly customizable.

> Note that this **requires Chart.js 2.7.0 or later**.

Use it by including it under the `plugins` key of your chart `options` as shown in the following solutions below.

---

**Solution #1.**

The configuration below will display your labels on the `top center` of each bar. See [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/8ljzzkn3v8).

```
var options = {
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      // use the formatter function to customize the labels displayed
      formatter: function(value, context) {
        return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
      },
      align: "top",
      anchor: "center",
      offset: 25,
      padding: -2,
      clip: true,
      font: {
        size: "16",
        weight: "bold"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

*However, this is not exactly like the screenshot you provided so,*

**Solution #2.**

Here's one workaround I can suggest to replicate the exact behaviour that you want.

> - `anchor: 'start'` and `align: -60`: that will bring your data label on top, left aligned
> - make your chart start at zero by setting `scale.ticks.beginAtZero` to `true`
> - `offset: 25`: distance (in pixels) to pull the label away from the anchor point
> - `padding: function() {}`: use a scriptable option to dynamically compute the left padding based on the label approximate size since adding a specific padding will only work if your labels have the same width that doesn't change which is not this case

See [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/6x8w6w5rz3) for a detailed overview of the configurations.

> This solution will work but it's *definitely not ideal* since the
>   position of these labels may change depending on the label size, bar
>   thickness, and the size of the chart.

Comment: That's an excellent and detailed answer. Thank you! You have a wealth of ChartJS knowledge.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks, I'm happy to hear that. I use it quite often at work and most of the time, I faced issues like this so yeah.:)